# javascript selectNodes on parsed xml

Tags: javascript, xml, selectnodes

How can I use the selectNode() function on a parsed XML message in javascript?

```
<script>
var xmlStr = "<tagName>some text here</tagName>";
var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
var nodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes('tagName');
</script>
```

I get error for this code:
*Uncaught TypeError: xmlDoc.selectNodes is not a function*

Comment: There’s no such thing as a `selectNodes` function on an `XMLDocument`. Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually [XmlDocument.SelectNodes method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes(v=vs.110).aspx) exists, but in the **.NET Framework**.

In **JavaScript**, you can use the [getElementsByTagName() method](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_get.asp)

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagName")[0];
```

Comment: @user6186801 you probably mean the code without the [0]. I.e., the nodes variable is an array, not it's first element. right?

Answer (score 1):

selectNode() is not on javascript, you meant that you are looking for equivalent function?

```
nodes.getElementsByTagName("tagname");
```

Comment: Thanks, totally acceptable answer. But I think APPinAIR answered a little faster.

Comment: It's a matter of time zone :-)